# Using an if statement in a macro

Tags: c

I need to map a macro to a right value depending on the option selected e.g

```
#define A { if (fel == 1) x; if(fel != 1) y; }
```

I want `A` to assume the value of `x` if `fel` is 1, else it must assume the value `y`.

Where am I missing it?

Comment: What makes you think it fails? A line `A;` gets expanded into `{ if (fel == 1) x; if(fel != 1) y; };` (and thus leads to errors if `fel`, `x`, or `y` do not exist. If they do, gcc complains about a "statement with no effect" but that could be what you wanted here).

Comment: Thanks to Samgak, the answer I was looking for is as follows

Comment: #define A    ((fel == 1) ? x : y)

Answer (score 3):

Macros are preprocessor directives, meaning - they are expanded before the compilation and before runtime.

So, the way you've written this, `A` will literally be replaced by `{ if (fel == 1) x; if(fel != 1) y; }`, not by `x` or `y`.

Macros can be avoided most of the time. Why not just use `A` as variable, not as macro?

If `fel` is compile-time known constant OR a macro itself, there are options with `#if`, but it looks like it's a normal variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Macro substitution is done at preprocessing stage and you can't set it based on a runtime condition.

Instead you can define `A` as a variable:

```
A = (fel == 1)? x: y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the macro using the ternary operator:

```
#define A    ((fel == 1) ? x : y)
```

The macro will only work if you use it in a context where `fel` and `x` and `y` are all in scope.

Comment: If one insist on using icky macros, it would make more sense to do `#define A(a) { if (fel == 1) a=x; if(fel != 1) a=y; }` Note that the code you proposed is not equivalent to the original code.

Comment: It's not equivalent but I assumed that the OP's intent is to evaluate A to x or y based on fel, and that the provided code wasn't working. There's no need to provide code equivalent to to a piece of non-working code

Comment: It compiled successfully. I will proceed it to check if it actually works.

Comment: `if (fel == 1) x(); if(fel != 1) y()`is very different from `(fel == 1) ? x() : y()`.

Comment: @Lundin yes I already agreed they are different and explained why that isn't important. What matters is the OP's plain English explanation of the desired behaviour, not the code posted. The question was "provide a macro that does X" not "provide a macro equivalent to code Y"

Answer (score 0):

`if` is a statement, not an expression, thus it doesn't return any value. You need to write it as an expression, like using ternary operator, as suggested by others, or use [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)